# MySQL Error 1064 Incorrect Syntax for LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE

Tags: mysql

Trying to load csv file.

I can load this query without issue:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/Users/ovoJa/Downloads/VEN01_527.csv'
INTO TABLE venom
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
(status, appid, phone, year, firstname, lastname, address, make, model, city, state, zip, count);
```

If I try to add IGNORE 1 ROWS to this statement to skip the header row I get a syntax error.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/Users/ovoJa/Downloads/VEN01_527.csv'
INTO TABLE venom
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
(status, appid, phone, year, firstname, lastname, address, make, model, city, state, zip, count)
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

Comment: Please refer to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html for correct syntax

Comment: `IGNORE 1 ROWS` has to go before the list of columns.

Comment: SQL is very strict about the order of clauses in queries.

Comment: worked perfect, thank you!

Comment: mark this as solved please @Rakonu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IGNORE 1 ROWS has to go before the list of columns. – Barmar (Source)